# Garden hose instability

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, fluid-dynamics, flow, stability

When a tap connected to a garden hose is turned on, the hose
wriggles like a snake that went berserk.
Is it because of the force offered by the stream of water to the hose wall when it gets deflected? If that is the case, the force should result in a gradual increment in the curvature of the pipe at any point of deflection. Then how can we can explain the oscillation of the hose end from this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of: [What is the term for hose fluctuating movements during flow?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/47726/)

Comment: Are you saying that the end of the hose is moving?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it's basically the same kind of instability that's responsible for the flapping of flags in the wind. If you have a curved hose, then the resulting pressure gradient tends to increase the curvature, causing instability.

Comment: Your last sentence is interesting. Could you please provide some reference/calculation(qualitative)?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, at any point of deflection, there would be a gradual rise in the curvature of the pipe. In the example below, the curvature at point $A$ of the pipe increases with time.[image]

However, after sufficient curvature is established, there arises newer points of deflection, e.g., point $B$ and $C$ below.

[image]

The forces on these two points will tend to straighten out point $A$. This happens until the curvature at A shifts to the opposite direction. The hose assumes a slightly curved configuration (just like in the first figure, but this time in the opposite direction).

[image]

The point A oscillates from left to right, giving a wriggling effect to the pipe. Depending on several factors, the forces on point B and C could also instead increase the curvature at A, eventually twisting the pipe at A, causing to shift in the other direction.

Please note, the actual movement of the pipe is not as predictable/straightforward as above and is in fact quite random.

Answer (score -1):

I think it is due as mass of water "m" as flows from cross sectional area "a" from the pipe starts to thrash water on ground and as it releases water , rebounded water after hitting ground starts to put pressure on pipe back and it moves upward being unstable and again after falling the water force like previous starts to act on pipe, creating a snake like movement.

Comment: No, it's not due to the water rebounding off a different external body. Forces on the inner surfaces of the pipe contribute to hose instability