Why will a hose make thrust?
Why will a hose make thrust? I thought the thrust will be made at the point where the fluid accelerates, such as the exit point of a pump or high pressure reservoir. Why will the thrust and force be felt at the end of a hose, around the curves and all?
Or you could also think of a straight hose. There is no place in the hose for the pressure to act (to make thrust), so why would thrust be felt at the end of it? For an example, imagine a firehose spraying water.
Edit : In this case, there is no nozzle on the hose and it is a constant diameter.

Does it have a nozzle?   Nozzles can accelerate the water at the end, even on a straight hose.
https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/47726/what-is-the-term-for-hose-fluctuating-movements-during-flow

@BowlOfRed Yeah I should've included that in the question. In this case, I'm considering it without a nozzle.

Does anyone know why this post is getting downvoted?

I think you're forgetting to account for changing mass; while the elementary definition of force is $F=ma$, which is the case for constant-mass systems, it is generalized to $F=\frac{dp}{dt}$ where $p$ is momentum. The thrust can be calculated using the momentum flux at the exit:
$$F_{exit}=\dot{m}v_{exit}=\rho A v^2_{exit}$$
with $\dot{m}$ representing the mass flow rate.
One way that you can think of this is Newton's third law: for every action there is an equal and opposite reaction; the action being the water leaving the hose, and the reaction being the thrust.
